# Shiny Interactive plots with leaflet map doing click change the data of charts

Tags: r, leaflet, shinydashboard, r-highcharter

I have a leaflet map in shiny, a chart (inside a pop up and behind the map) so i need to change the charts depending to the country i made the last click.
[image]

I tried with this code call the clicked country but doesnt work when i put it in a chart

```
    clickpais <- input$mymap_shape_click
clickpais<- clickpais$id
pais<-table_id()[table_id()$idtable==clickpais,]$nametable
```

ando also i tried with observeEvent with no result

```
      observeEvent( input$mymap_shape_click,{

    if(is.null(click)){}
    else{
      p_click<- input$mymap_shape_click 
      p_click<-  p$id
      print(p_click)
    }
  })
```

The app whith the data are in this link if any one could help or want to replicate for your work [INFORMATION](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1AtN1W0jUCQMlb2IqTOw_Yk-AvXIxo1UC?usp=sharing) I appreciate your help.

Comment: Your post contains too much code and it is not reproducible so it is hard to understand what you really want. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to know how to a make a minimal, reproducible example

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i will see the link and change my post.